# Am i wrong or is this a Visual Studio 2013 regex bug?

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++, c++11, gcc

I have a regex which is to remove extra vml tags from a HTML page.

```
    std::string regstr = R"(<!\[if !vml\]>([\s\S]*?)<!\[endif\]>)";
    std::regex regex(regstr, std::regex_constants::ECMAScript);
    std::smatch mr;
    std::string str = R"(</v:shape><![endif]--><![if !vml]>
<img width=234 height=383 src="file:///C:\Users\jcyangzh\AppData\Local\Temp\msohtmlclip1\01\clip_image002.png" v:shapes="110x110">
<![endif]></span></span><span lang=EN-US><o:p></o:p></span></p>)";
    if (std::regex_search(str, mr, regex)) {
        std::cout << "match found: " << mr.size() << "\n";
        for (size_t i = 0; i < mr.size(); ++i) {
            std::string strrep = mr.str(i);
            std::cout << "index: " << i << "\n string: " << strrep << "\n\n";
        }
    }
```

For GNU GCC Compiler 4.9.2 (latest tdm-gcc Windows port), the above code works. The regex I used does match.

[image: gcc_regex_match_result]

But for Visual Studio 2013 Update 4, the regex does not work, and `std::regex_search` returns `false`.

If I replace the key pattern `[\s\S]` with `(\s|\S)`, there will be **3** matches.

[image: vc_2013_update4_regex_match_result]

Is `[\s\S]` a valid C++11 Ecma regex, or is this a bug of VS2013 Update 4?

Comment: `[\s\S]` is a valid `ECMAScript` regexp. See the **Escape characters** bullet at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/#character_classes

Comment: There is only one match in both of your screenshots, just that you have one extra capturing group from `(\s|\S)` in the second screenshot.

Comment: Everybody should know you can't use regex to parse HTML.

Comment: @Puppy: Sure, yeah, but sometimes you don't need to pull out the 800-pound gorilla for a small job. If the OP wants to use regex and it works in his use case, there's no need to beat a dead horse.

Comment: @Cornstalks: If the 800-pound gorilla is the correct tool, then you should pull it out for the job.

Comment: @Puppy: Actually I am using MSHTML to parse HTML, but html generated by word has vml tags which need removed before fed to MSHTML parser.

Comment: I use the [online MSVC compiler provided by M$ here](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/), and it displays the correct result: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0fQPO.png But the online compiler, according to the blog, is a development branch, so it might not be the same as what you have,

Comment: It would be convenient if you included a `main()` and `#include` statements so I could just copy 'n' paste your code and test it out, rather than having to put them in myself. It's a small but nice part of providing a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Anyway, clang 3.5 produces the same results as gcc, so I'm going to guess it's a bug in VC++.

Comment: @Cornstalks: By default, Clang uses libstdc++, just like GCC, so you should not get a different result on library questions like this one between Clang and GCC.

Comment: @Puppy: Not on OS X. It uses libc++ by default. Heck, Apple doesn't even ship GCC/libstdc++ anymore.